# How to install InnoDB plugin in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

i am using MySQL 5.6 right now and i know that it have `InnoDB` engine by default but i want to enable `InnoDB` plugin. 
i have searched whole day for that on internet but i can't find proper solution.

if i use

```
INSTALL PLUGIN InnoDB SONAME 'ha_innodb_plugin.dll';
```

than i get error like

```
Function 'InnoDB' already exist.
```

than i tries to uninstall it like

```
UNINSTALL PLUGIN InnoDB
```

than i got error like

```
Plugin InnoDB does not exist
```

Please help me how to install/uninstall plugin

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-installation.html says:

> When you use the InnoDB storage engine 1.1 and above, with MySQL 5.5 and above, you do not need to do anything special to install: everything comes configured as part of the MySQL source and binary distributions.

In other words, only in MySQL 5.1 did you need to install the InnoDB plugin. In all later versions of MySQL, don't do anything. You already get the InnoDB implementation that used to be known as the "plugin."